# SQLiteException: no such table given that it does exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I had an external database, I Copied it to the internal storage, I checked in the Device Files Explorer if it has been copied successfully, I found it there, I tried changing the version and clearing the app storage, but no result.

[image]

this is the error I am getting :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<PackageName>.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MSG_CAT (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM MSG_CAT
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MSG_CAT (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM MSG_CAT
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
      at <PackageName>.database.DatabaseHelper.getListProduct(DatabaseHelper.java:60)
      at <PackageName>.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
```

The class I used to creat and copy the database from the assets folder is 
:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DBNAME = "msgDb.db";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/<PackageName>/databases/";
private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 2);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(newVersion>oldVersion)
        copyDatabase(mContext);
}

public void openDatabase() {
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase != null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}

private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.d("MainActivity","DB copied");
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public List<Category> getListProduct() {
    Category category = null;
    List<Category> CategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MSG_CAT", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        category = new Category(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2));
        CategoryList.add(category);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return CategoryList;
}

public Category getProductById(int id) {
    Category product = null;
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MSG_CAT WHERE ID = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    product = new Category(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2));
    //Only 1 resul
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return product;
}
```

Proof of the table existence:

[image]

I tried everything to solve this problem, but nothing came out.

## UPDATE

I found that the problem is only on the Pixel 2XL running Android P, I tested the app on other phones and emulators, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: table might exist, but there is a probably of connecting wrong database or schema as well. Did you verified that?

Comment: @Ravi I dont understand

Comment: I meant, are you sure, you are connecting to same database where you have table ? Sometime, you will have wrong JDBC confirgutraion

Comment: If the db is prepopoulated and you do have a backup, delete it from the device/emulator or uninstall the app and rerun after you put the CREATE statement inside onCreate(). If the app runs without a problem and it finds the table this will be a proof that this table does not exist now in the db.

Comment: well, I made a test if the db exists it gives a positive result, like this
`private boolean dbExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }`

Comment: The db may exist, but does the table exist?

Comment: yes of course it does, I tested this app on an other device, everything worked perfectly, but the device I am having problem with is Pixel 2XL running Android P.

Comment: I suspect your issue is that there doesn't appear to be an attempt to copy the db when there is no original database. i.e. you only copy db via onUpgrade and that only runs if there is a database. As no db exists empty db is created (no tables added) version set to 2. Subsequent runs no onUpgrade because db at version 2, again no tables............

Comment: @MikeT no that's completely no it, I found that the problem is only in a particular phone, which is Pixel 2XL, for other devices it is working perfectly.

Comment: And what if you uninstall the app the reinstall it ?

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe I already done that many times, tried clearing the storage only, reinstalling ...

Comment: @forpas if the database didn't exist then any attempt well before a message saying **table not found** (unless purposefully written outside of SQLiteDatabase class) would result in another exception. Fact is the table hasn't been found, thus the database hasn't been copied, so the process hasn't properly anticipated/trapped/reported such a scenario and thus a new database is created with only the initial tables **sqlite_master** and **android_metadata**, which would be seen if the actual database were looked at.

Comment: @MikeT this is really confusing, as why does it not work on a particular device, and does work on others. 
my mind has been blown !!!

Comment: I would suggest adding log statements in while testing e.g. in onCreate method, onUpgrade method. Plus things can get complicated due to cacheing when  copying db when it has already been opened, as per in the onUpgrade method (db has been opened for the user_version to be retrieved). Ideally you should do the check's before hand. May work on putting something together. Other things is hard coding path does appear to have issues with later version of android. So really it's better to use the Context's **getDatabasePath** method.

Comment: have you actually tried running the app a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Here, the onCreate callback is empty in your code. Create the table in onCreate callback using the SQLite standard syntax of creating tables:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
//execute the query to create the table with columns;

db.execSQL(YOUR_QUERY);
}
```

Then uninstall the app and reinstall it to recreate the db with all tables.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a database, I already have a database in the Assets folder, I copy it successfully, I check if there's a database, I get a positive response that it does exist, but when I try to query data from a particular table I get the exception. 
All that is happening in one of my testing phones which is Google Pixel 2 XL running Android 9, whereas all the other phones and emulators run the app perfectly, I hope you understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

---

## Please Note

The **DatabseHelper** code below does not include the **`getListProduct`** and **`getProductById`** methods for convenience.

---

I believe that the issue should have been evident from the log. But basically if the database doesn't exist and that you are copying the db after the DB has been opened (no DB it will not be opened thus no copy done).

The below fixes a few issues.

The main issue by checking whether or not the db file exists at the expected location. i.e. it doesn't try to open the database but sees if the file exists. If it doesn't then it copied the db before any attempt is made to open it by doing this when the DatabaseHelper is instantiated.

Furthermore, opening the database using `mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);` will result in the database being opened WITHOUT the potential for the onUpgrade method being run. That is you've opened the Database other than via the SQLiteOpenHelper subclasss, so it doesn't help you.

An issue, perhaps, is that you have `<PackageName>`. However, hard coding the database path is potentially asking for problems so the path is determined according to the Context's **getDatabasePath** method *(highly recommended to only use this unless placing the Database elsewhere)*.

Hopefully the following will allow you to move on.
Note I strongly suggest deleting the App's data, uninstalling the App before.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "msgDb.db";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/<PackageName>/databases/"; //<<<<<<<<< Shouldn't hard code path, really this package name????
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, 2);
        this.mContext = context;
        //<<<<<<<<<< Copy database if need be
        if (!ifDBExists()) {
            copyDatabase(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("ONCREATE","WARNING!!!! onCreate method shopuldn't be invoked"); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            Log.d("ONUPGRADE","Attempting to copy database"); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
            copyDatabase(mContext);
    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (mDatabase != null) {
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database file exists
     * @return
     */
    private boolean ifDBExists() {
        File db =  new File(mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath());
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        File dbdir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        Log.d("COPYDATABASE","Initiating copy of database");
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
            String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getAbsolutePath(); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
            //String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME; // relies on hard coded
            int bytes_copied = 0;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);

            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "DB copied");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void logMsgCatTable() {
        openDatabase();
        Cursor csr = mDatabase.query("MSG_CAT",null,null,null,null,null, null  );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

- Note when happy remove the log messages.
- Note also refer to/read the comments.
- **NOTE read on as there are still issues with the above**

Running the above from a very basic MainActivity, as per :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.logMsgCatTable();
    }
}
```

### First run :-

```
018-11-26 11:25:47.286 2597-2597/? D/COPYDATABASE: Initiating copy of database
2018-11-26 11:25:47.287 2597-2597/? D/MainActivity: DB copied
2018-11-26 11:25:47.302 2597-2597/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9bd3b6b
2018-11-26 11:25:47.302 2597-2597/? I/System.out: 0 {
2018-11-26 11:25:47.302 2597-2597/? I/System.out:    ID=1
2018-11-26 11:25:47.302 2597-2597/? I/System.out:    COL1=mcat col1 001
2018-11-26 11:25:47.303 2597-2597/? I/System.out:    COL2=mcat col2 001
2018-11-26 11:25:47.303 2597-2597/? I/System.out: }
2018-11-26 11:25:47.303 2597-2597/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- Note DBVERSION (aka user_version in SQLite not set/touched)

### Second Run :-

As above EXCEPT first 2 messages in the Log (i.e. DB not copied nor has onUpgrade been run as the DBVERSION is set to 2).

### Third run

Added another row in SQLite tool, copied DB back into assets folder but didn't change the user_version. After replacing the original DB with the modified DB and increasing the DBVERSION (`super(context, DBNAME, null, 3);`) :-

As per above doesn't copy the updated DB as `onUpgrade` doesn't run as you bypas the helper.

Amending the code to :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "msgDb.db";
    public static final String DBLOCATION = "/data/data/<PackageName>/databases/"; //<<<<<<<<< Shouldn't hard code path, really this package name????
    public static final int DBVERSION = 3; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED STAGE 2
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION); //<<<<<<<<<<CHANGED STAGE2 
        this.mContext = context;
        //<<<<<<<<<< Copy database if need be
        if (!ifDBExists()) {
            copyDatabase(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("ONCREATE","WARNING!!!! onCreate method shopuldn't be invoked"); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            Log.d("ONUPGRADE","Attempting to copy database"); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
            copyDatabase(mContext);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED STAGE2 (checks the user_version, closes the DB does the copy, then opens the DB)
    public void openDatabase() {
        String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            return;
        }
        mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        if (mDatabase.getVersion() < DBVERSION) {
            mDatabase.close();
            copyDatabase(mContext);
            mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        if(!mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            Log.d("OPENDATABASE","For some reason the Database cannot be opened!!!!!!!!!! ");
        }
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (mDatabase != null) {
            mDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database file exists
     * @return
     */
    private boolean ifDBExists() {
        File db =  new File(mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath());
        if (db.exists()) return true;
        File dbdir = new File(db.getParent());
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            dbdir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        Log.d("COPYDATABASE","Initiating copy of database");
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
            String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getAbsolutePath(); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
            //String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME; // relies on hard coded
            int bytes_copied = 0;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);

            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "DB copied");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void logMsgCatTable() {
        openDatabase();
        Cursor csr = mDatabase.query("MSG_CAT",null,null,null,null,null, null  );
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

## **NOTE The above is the code that should be used as the basis for fixing the issues.**

### Fourth run :-

```
2018-11-26 12:03:28.984 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages D/COPYDATABASE: Initiating copy of database
2018-11-26 12:03:28.985 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages D/MainActivity: DB copied
2018-11-26 12:03:28.993 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@7edd361
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out: 0 {
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out:    ID=1
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out:    COL1=mcat col1 001
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out:    COL2=mcat col2 001
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out: }
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out: 1 {
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out:    ID=2
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out:    COL1=mcat col1 002
2018-11-26 12:03:28.994 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out:    COL2=mcat col2 002
2018-11-26 12:03:28.995 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out: }
2018-11-26 12:03:28.995 3188-3188/so53468569.so53468569messages I/System.out: <<<<<
```